# Problems when trying to load a Font

Tags: android, andengine

I have a method that includes font:

```java
private void loadMenuFonts()
{
    FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("font/");
    final ITexture mainFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    font = FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(), mainFontTexture, activity.getAssets(), "font.ttf", 50, true, Color.WHITE, 2, Color.BLACK);
    font.load();
}
```

I get an error that says this from LogCat:

```
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984): java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.graphics.Typeface.(Typeface.java:175)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:149)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(FontFactory.java:172)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at com.shark.ResourcesManager.loadMenuFonts(ResourcesManager.java:98)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at com.shark.ResourcesManager.loadMenuResources(ResourcesManager.java:59)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at com.shark.base.SceneManager.createMenuScene(SceneManager.java:76)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at com.shark.GameActivity$1.onTimePassed(GameActivity.java:87)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:98)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:597)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:585)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:56)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:548)
02-16 21:59:37.288: E/AndroidRuntime(1984):     at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:820)
```

The error that occurs is `createStrokeFromAsset`.

Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: try with another font file which is not default font

Answer (score 0):

check if
1- directory font exists directly in directory assets
2- a truetype font exists in directory font with name font.ttf

if above file and directory exists replace with other rtf font.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and it turned out that the font file was called "font.TTF" not "font.ttf". Changing this in the `createStrokeFromAsset()` method worked for me. Looks like you might have a similar problem.